# ns records for subdomain in aws route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I'm using Route 53 for most of my website DNS needs but I have a question I couldn't find a clear answer for on Amazon's (usually very good) support docs.

It states everywhere in support not to change or remove the ns records for a hosted zone. But can I add ns records for a subdomain?

I'm migrating a site to Route 53 that requires ns records to point to a 3rd party for email. The current DNS set up is as follows:
[image: Original subdomain ns records]

When I come to move the parent domain to Route 53 can I add those records into the parent domain hosted zone as below or would I need to create a new hosted zone just for the sub-domain?
[image: AWS subdomain ns records]

Answer (score 1):

You can change the NS record in Route53 to add other DNS servers in the list or remove existing ones, but this is only required in very specific setups.

From your description, it seems you're simply trying to migrate the existing DNS settings from another provider to Route53. If this is the case, then you'll probably be using the AWS provided name servers exclusively for your domain, so the NS value that you have in Route53 is already what it should be and there's no need to change it.

The only reason why you would change the NS value is if you use other DNS servers (secondary DNS servers), separate from the ones Amazon has assigned to your hosted zone (possibly for redundancy, but the ones that Amazon provides already offer enough redundancy).

**UPDATE (based on comments below):**

If the subdomain user other name servers (it's delegated), then you'll need to create a new NS record in the hosted zone for that subdomain:

`email.primary-domain.com. IN NS other-ns.dns-provider.com.`

In this case, you'll need to leave the NS record for the root domain unchanged.

Comment: This is a specific setup. I've edited my question to make it a little clearer. I am moving the primary domain into Route 53 and that will be using the AWS name servers. But the subdomain `email.primary-domain.com` needs to have specific name server records set. So my question is, can I just add these to the parent Hosted Zone in Route 53 as illustrated in the last screenshot?

Comment: If the subdomain user other name servers (it's delegated), then you'll need to create a new NS record for that subdomain (e.g. `email.primary-domain.com. IN NS other-ns.dns-provider.com.`. In this case, you'll need to leave the NS record for the root domain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks. So it can be set up in the same Hosted Zone then.